# Show dropdown option in a column based on other column value

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown for a column in Excel to restrict the user to enter only those particular values. I'm able to do it easily with **Data Validation** option. But the problem is now I need to restrict the dropdown based on specific values. Like for example I have columns `Type` and `Variety`:

```
|--------------------------------|
|  Type        |     Variety     |
|______________|_________________|  
| hardware     |   *dropdown1*   |
|--------------------------------| 
| software     |   *Dropdown2*   |
|--------------------------------| 
| software     |   *Dropdown2*   |
|--------------------------------| 
| Hardware     |   *dropdown1*   |
|--------------------------------|
```

**dropdown1** will have options like Nut, bolt, pinion, button

**Dropdown2** will have options like License, validity, version

For `hardware` I should do one set of options in dropdown and for `software` I need a different set of dropdown options.

How can I achieve this / can this be achieved only through a macro or are any simple solutions available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **dependent dropdown** without *VBA*

Put a list of *fruits* in column **C**, a list of *dogs* in column **D** and a list of *cats* in column **E**.  The DV dropdown in cell **A1** will allow the user to select either "fruit" or "dog" or "cat".

In cell **A2** we setup Data Validation with the List option and the formula:

```
=IF(A1="fruit",C1:C4,IF(A1="dog",D1:D4,E1:E4))
```

[image]

Now if you pick a category in **A1**, cell **A2** will show the items for that category!

Comment: Thanks :) @Gary's Student. And how do i check for string(hardware/software) for entire column. U gave A1="fruit" but i need to search for whole column isn't it?

Comment: @Crazy2crack  Once you have correctly setup ***DV*** for a single cell, copy that cell down the column.